# Connecting Azure Activity Log to Log Analytics instance using Az CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line-interface, oms

Is there a way to configure Azure Activity logs to be forwarded to a Log Analytics instance using Azure CLI?

Hopefully equivalent to the PowerShell command:

```
New-AzureRmOperationalInsightsAzureActivityLogDataSource -ResourceGroupName <LogAnalyticsOMSWorkspaceResourceGroupName> -WorkspaceName <LogAnalyticsOMSWorkspaceName> -Name <NameOfThisOperationalInsightsAzureActivityLogDataSource> -SubscriptionId <SubscriptionId>
```

Comment: None for now according to https://feedback.azure.com/forums/598699-azure-cloud-shell/suggestions/37143496-azurecli-support-for-new-azurermoperationalinsight. Vote up please.

Answer (score 0):

Significant changes have been made to [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/terminology) recently, with different services being consolidated in order to simplify monitoring for Azure customers.

Dedicated Azure CLI commands under the set [az monitor activity-log alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/monitor/activity-log/alert) are available for managing activity log alert rules.

To create a new activity log alert rule, use in this order:

- [az monitor activity-log alert create](https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/monitor/activity-log/alert#az-monitor-activity-log-alert-create): Create new activity log alert rule resource
- [az monitor activity-log alert scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/monitor/activity-log/alert/scope): Add scope for the created activity log alert rule
- [az monitor activity-log alert action-group](https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/monitor/activity-log/alert/action-group): Add action group to the activity log alert rule

To retrieve one activity log alert rule resource, the Azure CLI command `az monitor activity-log alert show` can be used. And for viewing all activity log alert rule resource in a resource group, use `az monitor activity-log alert list`. Activity log alert rule resources can be removed using Azure CLI command `az monitor activity-log alert delete`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-activity-log#cli

Comment: I think this does not do `New-AzureRmOperationalInsightsAzureActivityLogDataSource`.